# jQuery .css - Relative Percentage Values (+= / -=)

Tags: jquery, css

So today I tried to use relative value with jQuery's `.css()`.

```
$block.css({'margin-left': '-=100%'});
```

and this happend to div:

```
<div class="block" style="margin-left: -100px;">
```

jQuery seems to ignore percentages :( Sooo I did a little research and jQuery docs say:

> As of jQuery 1.6, .css() accepts relative values similar to .animate(). Relative values are a string starting with += or -= to increment or decrement the current value.

It has been [reported as a bug here.](http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/14484) I barely understand what they say doe. I can't figure out how to fix it.

Anybody has an idea how to make this code:

```
$block.css({'margin-left': '-=100%'});
```

Do this:

```
<div class="block" style="margin-left: -100%;">
```

Then:

```
<div class="block" style="margin-left: -200%;">
```

And so on... I now this can be done with `.animate()` but I want to avoid it, **I want to do it with css** for hardware acceleration.

Comment: Check this out: http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/14484

Comment: I know this, I even linked it in my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What they're saying there is that it doesn't work right now. The [up to date bug report](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/issues/1711) shows a commit, which suggests that it will work in a version coming out soon. The latest milestone it was assigned to was 1.12/2.2, and so it will probably be fixed in v1.12 and v2.2.

In the meantime, three options:

1. You could use `animate` with a really short duration (here I'm doing an `inline-block` and only 25% so we can see the result):

```js
$(".block").animate({'margin-left': '-=25%'}, 10);
```

```css
.block {
   border: 1px solid black;
   display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class="block">012345678901234567890123456789</div>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

2. Look at [the commit](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/commit/6fb2cefc602cf8bd8b85373f480e978bb8978e37) and patch your copy of jQuery (or just use the current work-in-progress build).
3. Measure the element and do it with pixels:

```js
(function() {
        var $block = $(".block");
        $block.css('margin-left', -($block.width() * 0.75));
    })();
```

```css
.block {
      border: 1px solid black;
      display: inline-block;
    }
```

```html
<div class="block">012345678901234567890123456789</div>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: The reason why I asked this question is to avoid `.animate()`. I want to do it with css for hardware acceleration, thanks for your answer though!

Comment: @mwalbergh: Well, that pretty much leaves you with the option at the end of the answer (patching your copy of jQuery). :-) (Or, of course, measure the element and then use pixels with `.css`.)

Comment: Do you know any tutorial for that? I'm still a newbie to jQuery and I don't want to mess something up :P

Comment: @mwalbergh: No, but I do know that the jQuery project on github is *really* well-managed: If you pull the repo local, it builds and tests itself really easily, details [here](https://github.com/jquery/jquery). So if you don't mind being cutting-edge, it could be as simple as: Do the pull, do the build, and use the result, which will be the current work-in-progress.

Comment: I'm a newbie-newbie to github, but I'll try doing what you just said and let you know, thanks!